# Why is this image slider unresponsive and constrained?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Why is the image slider unresponsive when I have the proper code?

I’m making an image slider using html, css and jquery.
Heres the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.next').on('click', function() {
    var currentImg = $('.active');
    var nextImg = currentImg.next();

    if (nextImg.length) {
      currentImg.removeClass('active').css('z-index', -10);
      nextImg.addClass('active').css('z-index', 10)
    }
  });

  $('.prev').on('click', function() {
    var currentImg = $('.active');
    var prevImg = currentImg.prev();

    if (prevImg.length) {
      currentImg.removecLASS('active').css('z-index', -10);
      prevImg.addClass('active').css('z-index', 10)
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container1 {
  width: 540px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.slider-inner {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  padding: 3px;
  border: #666 solid 1px;
}

.slider-inner img {
  display: none;
  width 500px;
  height: 300px;
}

.slider-inner img.active {
  display: inline-block;
}

.prev,
.next {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 130px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -45px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.next {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -45px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
  <h1>Snaps</h1>
  <div class="slider-outer">
    <img src="images/arrow-left.png" class="prev" alt="Prev">
    <div class="slider-inner">
      <img src="snap1-min.jpg" alt="rosetta on sunset ave." height="666" width="1000" class="active">
      <img src="snap2-min.jpg" alt="rosetta on sunset ave." height="666" width="1000">
      <img src="snap4-min.jpg" alt="rosetta on sunset ave." height="666" width="1000">
      <img src="snap5-min.jpg" alt="rosetta on sunset ave." height="666" width="1000">
      <img src="snap6-min.jpg" alt="rosetta on sunset ave." height="666" width="1000">
      <img src="snap7-min.jpg" alt="rosetta on sunset ave." height="666" width="1000">
      <img src="snap8-min.jpg" alt="rosetta on sunset ave." height="666" width="1000">
      <img src="snap9-min.jpg" alt="rosetta on sunset ave." height="666" width="1000">
      <img src="snap10-min.jpg" alt="rosetta on sunset ave." height="666" width="1000">
    </div>
    <img src="images/arrow-right.png" class="next" alt="Next">
  </div>
</div>
```

I checked, double checked and triple checked and I can’t seem to figure out why it isn’t responsive. Also, why is it constrained in a box? I have vertical and horizontal pictures and I want their true sizes to show but they all seem to be constrained to a rectangular code and this rookie can’t figure out what he wrote to make them that way. I know y’all are a busy bunch so any solutions /suggestions/insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: .slider-inner { width: 500px;

Comment: And removecLASS doesn't exist. removeClass does.